# Moving documents from one server library to another server library programmatically

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013

I am a beginner in Sharepoint and given a task to write timer jobs. Once triggered, i want to move documents from one Sharepoint server library to another server library programmatically. So far my findings says that this can only be possible using **Client Object Model** because i am unable to create the second Sharepoint server (spUrl2) instance with `SPWebApplication.Lookup` method using **Server Object Model** and this method returns `null`.

I am running following code from first Sharepoint server (spUrl1):

```
SPWebApplication primaryWebApplication = 
    SPWebApplication.Lookup(new Uri("http://spUrl1"));

SPWebApplication secondaryWebApplication = 
    SPWebApplication.Lookup(new Uri("http://spUrl2"));
```

Now my question is that is it possible to do the needful using Server Object Model because this is very convenient and i want the same thing. If not then how can i possibly do this file movement as i couldn't find similar reference related to this on web.

Thanks for your support in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not use server side object model for the different farm access.

You can use Client object model, Rest APIs or sharepoint web services.

Comment: Please elaborate how can i use server side object model specifically by giving some example code.

Comment: Check the following link: http://blog.blumshapiro.com/blog/2012/08/22/sharepoint-2010-using-the-client-object-model-to-move-files-and-folders-across-site-collections-and-subsites/

Comment: The mentioned link is using the Client Object Model technique instead i am looking for any approach preferably using Server Object Model.

Comment: You can use server side object only on that farm on which the code is running . To access another farm's data you have to use CSOM or web services .